# How can I compare dates in related tables and use this to select the relevant record in a query? SQL / MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, relationship

The details of a course change over time. I need to be able to access the version of these details that was current when the course was run.

My tables are setup as follows (only relevant fields are shown):

**Class Details**

- ClassID (Primary key)
- CourseID (Foreign key)
- Commencement Date

**Courses**

- CourseID (Primary key)

**Course Versions**

- CourseVersionID (Primary key)
- CourseID (Foreign key)
- Course Version Start Date

I want to show one record per unique ClassID in a query with the following columns:

- ClassID
- The Course Version Start Date immediately below the Commencement Date (see examples below)

> Course Version Start Date (1) = 01/01/2010
>
> Course Version Start Date (2) = 01/11/2011
>
> Commencement Date is between (1) and (2) ~ The returned value is 01/01/2010
>
> Commencement Date is greater than (2) ~ The returned value is 01/11/2011
>
> Commencement Date is less than (1) ~ The returned value is nothing, this record doesn't show up.

- CourseVersionID

Solutions that can be used without much SQL knowledge (ie within the Access design view) are prefered but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL:

```
SELECT Class.ID, 
  Max(CourseVersions.CourseVersionStartDate) AS CourseVersionStartDate
FROM 
    (Course INNER JOIN Class ON Course.CourseId = Class.CourseId)
INNER JOIN 
    CourseVersions ON Course.CourseId = CourseVersions.CourseId
WHERE 
    (((Class.CommencementDate) > CourseVersions.CourseVersionStartDate))
GROUP BY Class.ID;
```

Or, since you prefer the access query designer:

[image: Access Query Design]

Comment: SQL is a generic tag and does not mean SQL Server alone, there are soecific tags, such as `t-sql` and `sql-server` for that. I am guessing that your first suggestion is t-sql, because it would never run in Access (Jet/ACE) SQL.

Comment: I have re-added the extraneous parentheses that Access requires - now the query is an exact copy and paste from the Access Query, except I've added some whitespace to make it easier to read.

Comment: I appreciate the effort to use the query designer and alter your original SQL.  
I was freaking out for a bit because I (naively) thought I could just add extra columns to the query and it would just sort itself out. Then I found this great article which explained it rather well http://access.mvps.org/access/queries/qry0020.htm

Answer (score 1):

Not quite query design window, though it can be viewed there, and it will return a line even if there is no date as per your fifth requirement.

```
SELECT [class details].classid,
       [class details].courseid,
       [class details].[commencement date],
       (SELECT TOP 1 [course version start date]
        FROM   [course versions]
        WHERE  courseid = courses.courseid
               AND
       [class details].[commencement date] > [course version start date]
        ORDER  BY [course version start date] DESC) AS commdate
FROM   [class details]
       INNER JOIN courses
         ON [class details].courseid = courses.courseid;
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work when I copied it as is. I also tried replacing "commdate" with [class details].[commencement date] (perhaps you can tell I am new to SQL) but to no avail.

Comment: @LittleJohn It was a cut and paste from the query design window from a set-up that used all the fields you mentioned. CommDate is an alias, replaceing it is not a good idea. What error did you get when you tried to run it?

Comment: I apologise, that was an extremely unhelpful comment I made. I originally misunderstood what the query was returning, now that I look at it properly I can see the problem. You said "[...] it will return a line even if there is no date as per your fifth requirement." However my 'fifth requirement' (I think this was what you were refering to) was "Commencement Date is less than (1) ~ The returned value is nothing, this record doesn't show up." Of course, using a filter easily fixes this.